# Watching for reponses (answers  + comments) of question asked by somebody else

Tags: support, answers, feed, responses, subscription

Is there a way to watch for **responses (i.e. answers + comments bellow answers)** of questions asked by somebody else?
I noticed that via RSS you can watch for your own responses or you can subscribe to answers for particular question, but what if you're very interested in a question asked by somebody else and you'd like to watch for the whole communication of solving that question?

thank you

Comment: You can click the star below the vote arrows then you'll see changes in your profile page in "favorites" tab e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/653379/xralf?tab=favorites

Comment: All questions have an RSS feed. It's at the bottom right of the page.

Comment: Note that I'm talking about **responses** not **answers**. Responses are **comments bellow the answer** too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried **starring the question**? This marks the question as one of your "favorites", and  will cause you to be automatically notified whenever a new answer is posted to the question.

[image: Starring a question on Stack Overflow]

Alternatively, you can use the RSS feed for the question, located in the bottom-right corner of the page.

[image: question feed link]

Comment: +1 for right and clear answer.

Comment: RSS feed is only for **answers (without comments)**. The star will cause that I will be notified on new **answers (without comments)** and without RSS channel.

Comment: @xralf: Yes, you don't get notifications on comments. They're not actually considered responses to the question. We only recently got the ability to leave comments at all. The focus of the site is on *answers*; comments are just noise. They serve a very important purpose of *clarification*, but it's not clear why you'd need to receive notifications about that on questions that aren't your own.

Comment: >> it's not clear why you'd need to receive notifications about that on questions that aren't your own. <br> Sometimes I have a feeling that the question is like I asked it myself and I would like to be informed about the whole communication. It's not often but It's useful functionality.