# Notify commenters of question edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications

There's currently an outstanding need:

***when a question needs clarification, and I'm discussing this with the OP, I receive notifications of their comments, but not edits.***

- And this is despite the fact that edits are **the recommended way** to reply to clarification requests!
- This has led some OPs to employ a kludge: in addition to editing the post, do a comment like "see the update".

Related:

- [Watching for reponses (answers  + comments) of question asked by somebody else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87315/watching-for-reponses-answers-comments-of-question-asked-by-somebody-else) - talks about answers, too. This one is only interested in the question
- [Notifications when somebody edits a post that you've commented on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186511/notifications-when-somebody-edits-a-post-that-youve-commented-on) - same on the purpose but it's completely blank what the OP wants to see as a result. In the end, they - and the answer - go off on a tangent about "commenting and not showing up" and some extravagant mechanisms. This one proposes a straightforward and simple solution: *notify on edits as well as comments.*
- [Notifications of edits to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149479/notifications-of-edits-to-questions) - focuses on distinguishing between "major" and "minor" edits instead which is a lost cause

Comment: @PatrickHofman This is exactly as it's meant to be: 1)the reason for this topic to exist is stated 2) the important part is highlighted. 3)"I propose to add... !" sounds plain immature and thus would repulse potential supporters.

Comment: I find the current layout very distracting. That's why I edited.

Comment: @ShadowWizard does sound similar but it's very unclear. It's confusing what the OP actually wants - thus the answer went off on a tangent. I'll edit the question with comparison (and am daring you to track the change without being notified! =) ).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev no idea why you think it's unclear. It's 100% clear for me.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, then I'll take over that question. I was always thinking that it was strictly prohibited to alter _anything, anywhere_ beyond the original author's intent. But if you are slamming it into my face this is the way to go...

Comment: **No, no, no**. I don't want notifications if any question (or answer) I have commented on gets edited. If a user thinks it is important enough to notify me he can @ping me. It is implemented (and I hope it isn't) then it had better be configurable so I can turn it off.

Comment: @DavidPostill can you tell me the principle difference between comments and edits as per [c873133](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/notify-commenters-of-question-edits?noredirect=1#comment873133_269469)? Because I don't see one.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev The difference is I get notified of comments on **my** questions/answers. I don't get notified of comments on **some other persons** questions/answer (unless I have commented and then get @ pinged). I get notified for edits to **my** questions/answers. I don't want to **ever** get notified for edits to **some other persons** questions/answer (whether I commented on **some other persons** questions/answer or not), unless something thinks it is very important and then @ pings me).

Comment: @DavidPostill `@user` is ineffective if there is more than one peer.

Comment: <shrug>. If the OP feels it is important to notify more than one user he can add multiple comments (one per @ user)

Comment: @DavidPostill [c873161](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/notify-commenters-of-question-edits?noredirect=1#comment873161_269468): Not quite. I also [get notified on any comment as long as I'm the sole commentator besides the OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74745/notify-commenters-of-replies-from-newbie-ops) - which has the same effect as getting notified on every comment unconditionally.

Comment: That's a corner case. And nothing to do with "@user is ineffective if there is more than one peer.". You are not making any sense to me.

Comment: @DavidPostill the gist is in some cases, I do get notified on every comment to a post I commented on, and this has proven helpful ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076652/in-app-purchases-dont-persist-between-app-installations?noredirect=1#comment53986098_33076652)).

Comment: I don't care. See my answer. Your proposal **doesn't scale**. I don't want my inbox filled with edit notifications. When you've made as many comments as I have I'm sure you would feel the same. You have only made **22 comments**. I have made **more than 18000**

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, edits are the best way to reply on a clarification request. Clarifications should go in the question, not in a comment.

The problem is though that you can't make distinction between users interested in updates or not. If I just post a comment to help OP, but don't want to participate in the post any more, I don't want a notification for every edit. If you were the person asking OP to clarify, you do want this.

Without a mechanism to make this distinction, this feature won't be very useful to the general user who just comments.

The current way of `@reply` is the best way to notify of an edit now. Those comments can be deleted once read, so if OP is interested in maintaining his post, it should be okay.

Comment: If you "aren't interested in participating", then don't start. You are getting notifications of comments in any case, so whether you get notified of edits, too, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev comments can be used to clarify what other commenters say, and not be directed at the OP. In those cases, the notification is probably noise.

Answer (score 3):

#### I am not interested in automated notications of edits to other peoples questions/answers

This is not because I don't care.

It is because your proposal would vastly increase the number of notifications I receive.

Here's why:

- As an active participent in SU for more than 1 year, I have made **5,634 Comments** and **12,518 Reviews** (many of which leave automated comments).
- **Every** time one of those **18,000+** questions or answers was edited I would get a notification.

**If 10% were edited I would get 1,800 notifications in my inbox**.

If 10% of the questions on SU where you have commented was edited you would only get 2 notifications (you have made only 22 comments and no reviews). On SO you would get about 250 notifications.

**Your proposal doesn't scale**.

---

#### What I like about the current system:

- I don't get notified of comments on some other persons questions/answer (unless I have commented and then get @pinged).
- I get notified for edits to my questions/answers.
- I don't get notified for edits to some other persons questions/answer (whether I commented on some other persons questions/answer or not), unless someone thinks **it is very important** and then @pings me.

---

#### What I dislike about the current system:

- Nothing. There aren't any bad things.

**Please leave the current system alone. It works.**

Comment: If a question has been read by 20 people thoroughly enough to leave a comment, minor issues with it have already been addressed.

Comment: It is discussable if _suggested edits_ should be included  - because they are prohibited to diverge from the OPs intent and thus are very likely to be minor.

Comment: If it works - how does it address the need outlined in the question?

Comment: Please read my updated answer.

Comment: **Your** need (and it's proposed solution) **don't scale**.

Comment: If any of your (as of this writing) 1235 SE network posts gets acted upon, you'll also get a notification. How many do you routinely get (to infer the percentage)? 10% is way overboard.

Comment: Very few. My posts are so good they don't need editing ;)

Comment: As seem to be mine. So, one would need some numbers to overthrow your claim... I do see from experience that edits are much rarer an event than comments.

Comment: Hehe. 50% is more accurate. Number to follow from Bob ;)

Comment: Unless I've calculated incorrectly, approximately [36% of all posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393119/percentage-of-posts-edited) and [51% of all questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393133/percentage-of-questions-edited) on SO have been edited.

Comment: @Bob That's not it. The rate of edits vs comments is needed - to roughly estimate the rate of notifications a person with N comments will get, assuming uniform distribution.

Comment: Assuming steady rate ratios throughout SO history, too, I get that [an average post is edited 0.63 times and commented on 1.55 times, thus giving 0.40 edits per comment](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/393181/504089/posts-edits-comments), over the [~6 years (~2200 days) of SO history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow). Thus, a person with `N` comments is expected to get `N*0.40/2200=N*1.8e-4` notifications/day.

Comment: To put this to scale, David and I with [955 and 943 comments @ SO](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/393191/504108/comments-by-user) and [5596 and 17 @ SU](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/revision/393197/504112/comments-per-user) would be getting `1.18` and `0.17` notifications per day, respectively.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Your query doesn't group simultaneous edits (SEDE considers title, body and tag edits separately) - not an issue when counting edited posts, but it means you can't use the same method to count total edits. Anyway, on average [each edit would end up notifying 0.77 users](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393211/average-comments-with-unique-users-excl-owner-per-edit-on-questions) - where notified includes all unique users who commented before the edit. Alternatively, you could say for every 1.3 unique posts you comment on you'll be notified of one edit (on average).

Comment: @Bob Not sure how to group (`CreationTime` might differ in microseconds). [Grouping by `RevisionGUID` (which I consider good enough - subrevision edits don't seem to be notified of - or considered by the system in general)](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/393181/504138/posts-edits-comments) gives `0.37` edits per comment - not much of a difference.